# Create a matrix of numbers and starting point for use in traversal/search programs

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a python class that establishes a grid of n x n numbers and then uses that grid for the purpose of depth-first and breadth-first search/traversal, based on a starting point in the grid.  The variables that would be defined when calling the class as part of a test are the `starting row` + `the starting column` (defining the start point) and the `size of the row` + `size of the column` (defining the two dimensional grid space).  the class starts like this:

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, start_row: int, start_col: int, size_row: int, size_col: int):
        #constructor
        self.graph = [[0] * size_col for _ in range(size_row)]
        self.bfs(start_row, start_col)
```

I was able to create the matrix based on what the inputs would be included while calling the object, which would look something like this:

```
def test_graph():
    g = Graph(3, 5, 8, 9)
```

The remainder of the code for the Breadth-First Search algorithm looks like this, in the same class built as another method:

## BFS function

```
def bfs(self,s):  # this is our function using params as 
                  # visited nodes, the graph, and the node

    # initialize  all vertices as not visited
    visited = [False] * (max(self.graph)+1)

    # create a BFS queue
    queue = []
    # mark the source node as visited and enqueue it
    queue.append(s)
    visited[s] = True

    # while loop to keep the routine running until nothing 
    #left to visit
    while queue:
        # remove a vertex from queue
        s = queue.pop()
        # get all adjacent vertices of the last considered 
        #vertex; if adjacency not visited, mark
        # ~ it visited and enqueue

        for i in self.graph[s]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                queue.append[i]
                visited[i] = True
```

The problem I am having is that my object is returning arrays of all zeroes as opposed to the outcome of the BFS.  Am I missing something in my Class that is causing the object to not execute the BFS method on the given Class inputs?

Comment: @rabinzel not sure why you edited my code but it looks like you removed my questions.

Comment: Everything still there, isn't it ? Just splitted the question from the code because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Rabinzel.  The way the side-by-side shows me is that the questions were removed.  Any ideas as to how I might approach the problem?

Comment: How is your code even returning 0s, it shouldn't work. You're calling bfs with 2 arguments whereas you've defined it with just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues in this

1. Calling `self.bfs()` with 2 arguments (row and col) while the definition has only one (`s`)
2. `max(self.graph)` would return a list, you can't initialize `visited` with that.
3. `s=queue.pop()` will actually make the function behave as dfs and not bfs. `.pop()` pops from the end of the list. If you have `[1,2,3]` and call `pop()`, `3` will be returned and behave as a stack. To make it behave like a queue, `queue.pop(0)` should be used.
4. Not sure what the logic is behind using a single dimension visited array and what `s` refers to.